# Cakephp is putting webroot in the url Or appears Blank Plage

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-3.0

I've been trying to create a view with data from database, but I have 2 lingering issues:

-> The page stays blank with the message:

```
No Data Received
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

-> When I click the link to controller that I want, cakephp passes in the url the following url:

`myDomain/webroot/controller`

I don't know why cakephp is puting `webroot` in the url.....

In the apache's `error.log` I have this error:

```
[Thu Apr 28 16:47:23.169213 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1619] AH00052: child pid 4737 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Apr 28 16:47:23.169217 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1619] AH00052: child pid 4738 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Apr 28 16:47:23.169222 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1619] AH00052: child pid 4800 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

The Code is here:

gist.github.com/TiagoSilvestre/abc00a8e6da0698754d7f9c1d28d3c9d

I hope someone can help me because this error already appears in 3 differents computers with differents SO(Linux and Windows), but always with apache.
Thanks

Comment: The problem most likely lies in apache+php themselves or some extension, because normally you do not get a segfault in an interpreted language. How do you have these set up?

Comment: Also it's better to post relevant code in the question itself